# Script to automatically create Projects and repositories in bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I am in the process of moving whole set of projects from TFS to Git.My project structure is as below:

```
Project 1:
---Repository1
---Repository2
---
---
---Repository10

Project 2:
---Repository1
---Repository2
---
---
---Repository20
```

So there are multiple projects and contain multiple respositories under each project. As I am moving my code from my local repository to Bitbucket, I end up creating each project and folder separately and manually. Instead is there any script that will automatically create this structure of Project and repositories for me in the Bitbucket? If yes, can someone pls share an example? TIA!

EDIT: I found a script that can actually do this : https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SCLI/pages/87720019/How+to+create+projects+based+on+a+template

[How+to+create+projects+based+on+a+template](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SUPPORT/pages/976289874/How+to+create+projects+based+on+a+template)

So my question is, to implement what is mentioned in the link, do I need to install Bitbucket CLI or can I get it done using Command line interface?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some Perl I use to import a repository into bitbucket:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use File::Basename;
my $numArgs = $#ARGV + 1;

if($numArgs < 2) {
 die "Usage: $0 [Bit Bucket Project e.g. FW, BDPE] [repo name] [-d dry run (optional)]";
}

my $bitbucketProject = lc $ARGV[0];
my $repoName = $ARGV[1];
my $dryRun = $ARGV[2];
my %moduleHash;
my $bitBucketServer = "localhost";
my $user = "admin";
my $password = "bitbucket";


print "Bit Bucket Project: $bitbucketProject\n";
print "Repository name: $repoName\n";

sub importRepo {

     my $command = sprintf("curl -u %s:%s -X POST -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -d '{
     \"name\": \"%s\",
     \"scmId\": \"git\",
     \"forkable\": true
     \}' http://%s:7990/rest/api/1.0/projects/%s/repos", $user, $password, $repoName, $bitBucketServer, $bitbucketProject); 

    if ($dryRun) {
      print "$command\n";
    } else {
    print "Doing import\n";
        system $command;
    }
    my $bitbucketUrl = sprintf("ssh://git\@%s:7999/%s/%s.git", $bitBucketServer, lc $bitbucketProject, $repoName);   
    my $gitCommand = sprintf("cd %s; pwd;  git repack -a -d -f; git push %s --mirror", $repoName, $bitbucketUrl);
    if ($dryRun) {
      print "$gitCommand\n";
    } else {   
       print "Running git\n";
       system $gitCommand;
    }

}

importRepo();
```

Then you can wrap around that with a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

BITBUCKETPROJECT=$1

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
echo "Usage: $0 [Bit Bucket Project] [Path to repos]"
exit 1;
fi

echo "Bit bucket project: $BITBUCKETPROJECT"

    for f in *; do
        if [[ -d $f ]]; then
          echo $f
          ./importRepository.pl $BITBUCKETPROJECT $f 
        fi
    done
```

Assumes that all of your repos have been cloned into the current directory.

https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/bitbucket-server/latest/bitbucket-rest.html

The example above doesn't create the project on Bitbucket, but it's a starting point.